# Union of a family of open intervals equals union of a countable subfamily

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that given a family of open intervals $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$
there exists a countable subfamily  $\{I_{k}\}_{k}^\infty$ such that
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k}=\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} I_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
I maybe thought of looking at the family of intervals whose coordinates are rational. This way, we can only find countable many sets in I that have an element which is not in any of the other open sets in I.

But I'm not sure how I would do it.

Thanks!

Comment: See if this can help you, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277137/union-of-a-family-j-of-open-sets-in-mathbb-rn-equals-union-of-a-countable